# How can I evaluate SQL Server 2014 performance?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I am currently working in a SQL Server 2008 environment.

My concerns regarded to performance are related to views and stored procedures execution time.

And despite the queries I develop, there are around 30 users operating ERP system, generating data reports.

I would like to know how can I test gains for DB performance once we migrate to SQL Server 2014, as I don't have deep knowledge of performance parameters, except time to execute queries.

From now, in my test environment, I executed a complex view in both versions and didn't realize consistent benefits from the old to the newer version.

I would appreciate any tip to check more specific results!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably wont get much performance increase, but you will have more tools to do your job more easily.

Comment: People have written entire books discussing performance and optimization.  Amazon and Google would be great places to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance tuning can be complex, and execution time is a great metric for comparing systems.  However, in the case of a side-by-side migration, you should consider the following as well:

1. CPU, Disk and Memory; are they comparable between systems?  Be sure to compare file placement as well.
2. Server configurations: settings found in sys.configurations.  By default, SQL Server is set up in a less than optimal fashion.  If your 2008 system has been around for a while, it may have been optimized.
3. Index fragmentation and maintenance; is it being performed on the old system, but not the new?
4. TempDB contention: are both of the systems set up optimally?

There's a lot of places to check, but those are some quick starting points.

Comment: I am testing both versions in similar server hardware settings, and index fragmentation and maintenance would be continued. My idea was to compare both in an equal level as I would obtain parameters to check any improvement. 
I will check further results regarding sys.configurations and TempDB, thank you for the suggestions!